# Letting a parent Rust process terminate without waiting for a subprocess

Tags: unix, rust, subprocess

I have a Rust process that is supposed to launch a subprocess and then immediately exit. This appears to work:

```
fn main() {
    // Intentionally drop the returned Child and exit
    Command::new("bash").args(&["-c", "sleep 10s; touch done"]).spawn().unwrap();
}
```

Running this process exits immediately and the `bash` process continues:

```
$ cargo build; target/debug/demo

$ ps aux | grep bash
dimo414         35959   0.0  0.0  4278616   1484 s001  S     1:12PM   0:00.00 bash -c sleep 10s; touch done
...
```

*However* if I add one more layer and try to invoke my binary and await its completion that also appears to wait for the subprocess, unlike what I observe in the shell. Here's an MCVE:

```
fn main() {
    let exec = std::env::current_exe().expect("Could not resolve executable location");
    // First re-invoke the same binary and await it
    if std::env::args().len() < 2 {
        println!("Ran Subprocess:\n{:?}", Command::new(exec).arg("").output().unwrap());
    } else {
        // In that subprocess spawn a long-running process but don't wait
        println!("Spawning Subprocess");
        Command::new("bash").args(&["-c", "sleep 10s; touch done"]).spawn().unwrap();
    }
}
```

```
$ cargo build; target/debug/demo
# doesn't terminate until the bash process does
```

Is there a way to allow the top-level process to complete without waiting for the nested process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.spawn) of `spawn`

> Executes the command as a child process, returning a handle to it.
>
> By default, stdin, stdout and stderr are inherited from the parent.

When you run self as a subprocess it spawns another subprocess with inheriting stdio from parent. Since your top-level process uses `output()` it will wait subprocess to finish and collect its all **output** ([reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.output)).

Let's demonstrate it like this:

**Root** ->  Sub1 -> **Sub2**

Sub2 uses stdout channel of Sub1, Root waits to collect all output from Sub1 which is still in use by Sub2, at the end of the day Root waits for Sub2 to finish.

Solution is; simply use `Stdio::null()` to send output to `/dev/null` since your Root process does not care about the output of Sub2.

```rust
fn main() {
    let exec = std::env::current_exe().expect("Could not resolve executable location");
    if std::env::args().len() < 2 {
        println!(
            "Ran Subprocess:\n{:?}",
            Command::new(exec).arg("").output().unwrap()
        );
    } else {
        println!("Spawning Subprocess");
        Command::new("bash")
            .stdout(Stdio::null())
            .stderr(Stdio::null())
            .args(&["-c", "sleep 10s; touch done"])
            .spawn()
            .unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, I should have realized that :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work for me.
You should just ignore the SIGHUP signal:

```rust
use std::os::unix::process::CommandExt;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    let mut command = std::process::Command::new("bash");
    command.args(["-c", "pwd; sleep 5; touch helloworld"]);

    unsafe {
        command.pre_exec(|| {
            // Ignore SIGHUP signal to prevent child process from being killed when parent exits
            libc::signal(libc::SIGHUP, libc::SIG_IGN);
            Ok(())
        });
    }
    command.spawn()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: What environment(s) have you tested on? I just re-tried the accepted answer (Ubuntu on WSL) and it works as expected, creating a `done` file after ~10s. Note that your example doesn't redirect stdout/err which is necessary for the subprocess to not be interrupted when the parent process' stdout/err are closed.

Comment: Hi @dimo414 , I'm sorry, I've tested it again on macOS and Ubuntu, and the accepted answer works fine. And I just remember that I  tested it in `vscode`(I clicked the `run` button that rust-analyzer displays above the main function) yesterday, and that's when the accepted answer does not work. This time I use `cargo run` in the terminal directly, so it's good. I think maybe the rust-analyzer will also send the `SIGHUP` to the our subprocess when its task is done.